# .net Entity Framework wont include all list elements in json

Tags: .net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Im trying to set up a REST API in .net core and im struggeling including all elements in the list inside 'Person'

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        LoanRequests = new List<LoanRequest>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BirthNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<LoanRequest> LoanRequests { get; set; }
}
```

LoanRequest Class:

```
public class LoanRequest
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Years { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Person Person { get; set; }


    public enum RequestStatus
    {
        NotLookedAt,
        Approved,
        Declined
    }
}
```

Method that includes the elements:

```
public List<Person> GetAllPersons()
    {
        try
        {
            return _loanDbContext.Persons
                                 .Include(l => l.LoanRequests)
                                 .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new List<Person>();
        }

    }
```

Method inside the controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public List<Person> Get()
    {
        return _dbAccess.GetAllPersons();
    }
```

Im using postman to test the api and after adding multiple persons and multiple LoanRequests to them this is whats displayed:

```
[{
    "birthNumber": "0123456783",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "phone": "99999999",
    "loanRequests": [{

      "id": 1,
      "amount": 123456,
      "years": 0,
      "status": 2
    }]
}]
```

I am notifyig its always displaying the first person and loanRequests.
I have tried debugging and there all the elements are included.

Comment: are you using correct conn string ?

Comment: var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=loanRequestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;";

But i do get some output though

Comment: @Gert Arnold 
Yes, i only have one database, and i have checked the database that the values are added